# How to make conditional statement based on column titles in R

Tags: r, dataframe, import, sum, r-colnames

I am exporting a dataframe to R
I want to set a condition so that if the column header matches any of the following name below

```
Data_design <- c( "age", "sex", "font")
```

Then an error is flagged in the condition if statement.

For instance, if I import the following table (busa) with the column header ( age, sex, location, geography)

The condition would give an error because the columns do not have the required column header which is age sex and font.

Please can anyone help me with this?  The code I have been able to do is below

```
if (sum(str_sort(colnames(busa)) == str_sort(Data_design)) <length(Data_design)){
print("Failed import structure test")
break
}
```

But I am getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understand, you want a test that only passes if all the data frame column names are in your `Data_design` - is that right?

If so you can check if the column names are in your list as follows:

```
names(busa) %in% Data_design

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

To distil that to a single test:

```
all(names(busa) %in% Data_design)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Really grateful for this

Answer (score 0):

You could try `grepl`. This will match the pattern of "age", "sex", "font" and will only return true if they are the only string in the column. Otherwise it will return false. Then invert the search with `!` and return the warning message.

```r
# make "^age$|^sex$|^font$"
patternSearch <- paste0("^",Data_design, "$", collapse = "|")

if(any(!grepl(patternSearch, x = names(busa)))) {
  warning("Failed import structure test")
}
# Warning message:
# Failed import structure test
```

EDIT:
To be fair Paul's solution is the faster more elegant version to solve the described problem.

Comment: also you can go the with `all` and without `!` as done by Paul. The more direct route.